# Count and group by day

Tags: mysql

I have a very basic table, consisting of an integer column and a timestamp column.

What's the query to count how many entries there are for each day?

When I use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM taps GROUP BY(DATE(time_stamp))` , I get the total number of rows int he table, rather than the number of rows for each `DISTINCT` date.

How do I need to modify the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward.

```
SELECT
    DATE(time_stamp),
    COUNT(1)
FROM taps
GROUP BY DATE(time_stamp)
```